# Increment my variable in a database with UPDATE in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, updates, increment

I get the variable 'stock' from my database. I would like increment my variable with an update with this code:

```
$stock = $_POST['stock']

$nom = 'salade';
$req=("UPDATE ingredients SET stock=$stock+1 WHERE nom = :nom;");
 $stmt = $db->prepare($req);

    // execute the query
    $stmt->execute(array('nom'=>$nom));
```

But the problem is that my variable increment by 8 and not by 1 because I have 8 element (salade,tomatoes, bread etc). I want to increment by 1 with UPDATE.

Thanks to reading me !

Comment: `SET stock=stock + $stock`

Comment: Why not increment before update like `$stock = $_POST['stock'] + 1;`

Comment: using a prepared statement but still including unsanitised user input directly ... thus making this open to sql injection.

Comment: You should not set the value from the post value. Let the database increase itself. See answer from @Gilkan

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you're saying all you need to is increment by 1 each row `WHERE nom = :nom` (I guess your actual code isn't wrong with $ instead of : or it wouldn't even "increment by 8" as you said you're already achieving... remember do edit this on your question, please):

```
UPDATE
    ingredients
SET
    stock=stock+1
WHERE
    nom = :nom;
```

Jusk pick what you already had and add 1 `stock=stock+1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this for variable in text query.

```
$req= ("UPDATE ingredients SET stock='".($stock+1)."' WHERE nom = :nom;");
```